# Error while removing data from DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm working on an archive software in C# and I need to delete only the selected row in a DataGridView, but when I try to execute the function the program delete all the rows in the DataGridView instead of only the one I select

Here is the code:

```
private void dgvFattDdt_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(dgvFattDdt.RowCount == 1)
        {
            dgvFattDdt.ClearSelection();
            return;
        }
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvFattDdt.SelectedRows)
        {
            //here I save the data of the row into textboxes
            txtColli.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txtDescMerce.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            txtUM.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            txtIso.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            txtLordo.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            txtTara.Text = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            txtPrezzo.Text = row.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            cbIVA.Text = row.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
            selectedRow = row.Index;
            ex_Colli = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            decimal.TryParse(row.Cells[9].Value.ToString(), out ex_Importo);
            int.TryParse(row.Cells[10].Value.ToString(), out ex_Iva);
            //------------------------------
            dgvFattDdt.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your problem is that you're modifying your collection while iterating it. This logic isn't safe because it could lead to some unexpected issues (like the removal of all your rows). You have the following alternatives:

1. Use a `for` loop iterating your `dgvFattDdt.SelectedRows` collection backward from the end and then remove your current `DataGridRow` object based on its index.
2. Use LINQ to store the indexes of the rows you need to remove and then iterate this indexes collection to remove your `DataGridRow` objects.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that u try to REMOVE an item from the list while you r running on the list, and its making an index problem for the list.

what you can do is 
copy the list to a temp list,
run on you temp list,
and delete from the real list

good luck